# What is the simplest way to encode a images link address to base64

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to automatically tweet photos sent into a channel in a discord server to twitter by using their api. I unfortunately can not find a good simple way to convert the images link address to base64 this is what I have so far

```js
const Twit = require('twit'),
 fs = require('fs'),
 path = require('path');
config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'config.js'));

const T = new Twit(config);
const imageToBase64 = require('image-to-base64');
const axios = require('axios').default;

success = ['756562982493749260'];

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { default: Axios } = require('axios');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.on('ready', () => {
 console.log(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`);
});
const imagePath = new Discord.MessageAttachment(attachmentnamedata);
message.attachments.first().url;

const b64content = fs.readFileSync(imagePath, { encoding: 'base64' });

Axios.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, function(
 err,
 data,
 response
) {
 if (err) {
  console.log('err', err);
 } else {
  console.log('image succesfully uploaded'),
   destination.forEach((channel) => {
    bot.channels.cache.get(channel).send(successEmbed);
   });
 }
});
```

Comment: Try looking for NodeJS buffers, you can use it to encode your links do Base64.